# Как запретить копирование текста с сайта WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Подскажите пожалуйста как поставить запрет на копирование текста на сайте(WordPress) ?. Или может есть какой то плагин ?

Comment: А запретить копировать текст с сайта вообще возможно? Даже если сделать текст невыделяемым (user-select: none) можно открыть dev-tools и скопировать его оттуда...

Comment: Как вариант можете скринить текст и загружать картинку :) (раздел безумие)

Comment: Никак. И, надеюсь, так будет и впредь.

Comment: Есть куча плагинов, способов и уловок, делающих Ваш сайт абсолютно непригодным для использования и не останавливающих тех, кто задался целью скопировать Ваш контент, но нет смысла пользоваться ими.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала ты создаёшь тег, например, `<a>`, а затем в `CSS` задаёшь ему `::before`, а свойство `content` и будет содержать этот текст. Выделить никак не получится, а через `Просмотр кода` не выйдет. Хотя есть один минус. Если это продвинутый пользователь, он может догадаться через панель `source` найти тот самый `.css` файл и найти в нём текст.